# How to show labels selectively in certain points in Line chart of HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart in HighCharts and I want to show some labels selectively when some values are above certain threshold. I looked into dataLabels and so on but I couldn't find a way to show labels selectively.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to show labels selectively as I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
You can do this with [`dataLabels.filter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.filter) properties. Something like this:

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  format: '{point.name}',
  filter: {
    property: 'y',
    operator: '>',
    value: labelfilter // the vale that y needs to be above.
  },
  style: {
    color: 'black',
    textOutline: 'none',
    fontWeight: 'normal'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `formatter` function:

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.y > 3) {
                return this.y
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d65w4su1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.formatter